# Why are ntpq -p and ntpstat showing different outputs of time differences and stratum value at all the times?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

Why are `ntpq -p` and `ntpstat` showing different outputs of time differences and  stratum value at all the times? And what does it mean "unspecified in the result from ntpstat", which one to believe?

Please refer to this output:

1. `ntpstat`

   ```
   synchronised to unspecified at stratum 4
   time correct to within 17 ms polling server every 8s
   ```
2. `ntpq -p`

   ```
       remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset   jitter
   *130.246.71.4 139.143.5.31     3 u    4    8  377   0.1520   0.0222   0.0249
    3. ntpq -p

        remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset   jitter
   +139.143.5.30 139.143.45.169   2 u    6    8  377   4.6551  -0.0357   0.0445
   *139.143.5.31 139.143.45.169   2 u    4    8  377   4.7170   0.0087   0.0240
   ```
3. `ntpstat`

   ```
   synchronised to unspecified at stratum 3
   time correct to within 17 ms
   polling server every 8 s
   ```